# Отсортировать строку с сохранением исходных индексов

Tags: python, алгоритм

Есть строка:

```
str = [200, 322, 12, 877, 392, 142, 406]
```

Как ее можно отсортировать с последующим сохранением индексов?

Желательно, наиболее быстрым вариантом. То есть, чтобы элемент 12, который после сортировки будет стоять на 1 месте, имел индекс 2, а не 0.

Возможно есть способ сделать это через словарь или добавить доп. список с индексами.

Comment: вам стоит почитать про типы данных в python.

Comment: Гм, а что вы понимаете под "имел индекс"? Если это реальный индекс, то он и должен стоять на третьем месте. Другое дело, если вы хотите иметь возможность узнать, а где этот элемент стоял до сортировки. Просто иначе теряется сам смысл...

Comment: @splash58 думаю, что смысла в данном случае все таки нет. "Задачу" можно решать, добавляя и меняя структуру данных. Дописал в основном вопросе, просто не знаю, как это технически быстро осуществить.

Comment: @Harry надо, чтобы их изначальные индексы сохранились. Безусловно, можно возвращаться к исходному списку каждый раз, но с точки зрения скорости работы алгоритма, это слишком долго.

Comment: Если не секрет для чего Вам нужно сохранять индексы? возможно то что Вы пытаетесь решить, решается другим образом. Ну и если в вопросе как вы пишете смысла нет, то лучше его удалить уступив место более полезным.

Comment: @DaniilLoban У меня есть строка со списком ЗП на входе. Условно Индекс - номер человека, значение под индексом - его ЗП. Далее даются два Индекса (отрезок, внутри которого осуществляется поиск) и одна ЗП. Необходимо найти индекс/индексы человека с такой ЗП. Я понимаю, что такое решается через бинарный поиск, но как правильно отсортировать значения в данном случае - без понятия.

Comment: т.е. основная задача воспользоваться бинарным поиском, для поиска человека с какой-то зп? поэтому Вы решили сделать сортировку. Ну из сортировок самое быстрое это вроде как quickSort не уверен что ее нужно писать самостоятельно, да и поиск можно решить штатно. Но думаю без преобразования структур не обойдется, думаю достаточно одного раза до тех пор пока данные не устареют

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант могу предложить создание структур `{'salary':x, 'id':i}` с которыми потом и работать:

```
ranked_users = [200, 322, 12, 877, 392, 142, 406]

# добавляем id
users_details = [{'salary':x, 'id':i} 
  for i,x in enumerate(ranked_users)] 

# cортируем
users_details.sort(key=lambda x: x['salary'])

# делаем любой поиск
user_id = next((x['id'] 
  for x in users_details if x["salary"] == 12 ), None)

# результат 
print(user_id) # 2
```

Вообще, конечно мне сложно представить ситуацию когда о сотрудниках известно только их порядковый номер и зп, и к тому же этих сотрудников столько, что скорость поиска по ним может быть существенна. Но возможно где-то так и есть. Иначе, я бы предложил использовать все же ООП подход, хотя, в рамках представленного вопроса это излишне.